# Sharing a matrix with the math community

Tags: matrix, reference-request

What would currently be the best way to share a matrix with the math community?

(I'm aware of [Matrix Market](http://math.nist.gov/MatrixMarket/) but it seems the last update was in 2007...)

Comment: Are you asking about the format to store the matrix, a website/platform to share or something else?

Comment: yes, a website/platform like matrix market where the math community is likely to look.

Comment: Sharing something is only useful if others find a use in it. What is the reason  why you want to share yours? If we know what's particular about it, we may be able to suggest the right forum to put it on.

Comment: It's a matrix from a nonlinear iteration of an incompressible Reynolds-averaged Navier-Stokes code which might be interesting for those working on block preconditioners without access to a RaNS solver

Answer (score 2):

If it happens to be sparse, you might also consider the UF collection:

https://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/matrices/

I don't know that it's especially active in the last few years, a cursory search seemed to suggest the last additions were around 2013 or so.

Answer (score 1):

Most languages have the ability to read HDF5 files in some fashion. That would be a very cross-compatible way to save a sparse matrix to a file to share.